# Which octave learning can be postponed by beginner while eartraining from 7 octave computer software for piano?

Tags: piano, software, ear-training, octave, absolute-pitch

If a beginner wants to ear train absolute pitch of piano from computer software which is showing 7 octaves, which  octaves can he can omit at beginning ? 7th ,6th octave or 1st ,2nd octave? Or should he begin from 1st octave even if he doesn’t want to sing or play piano?(He wants only to ear train)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the middle pitches, around middle C and work an octave up and down. Those pitches are around where a lot of people sing and several well known instruments are tuned.

When you're getting good there, gradually spread higher and lower. The top and bottom end of the sonic spectrum are more difficult, so get to them progressively. No point in making life difficult.

Comment: Yes,no point in making life difficult.